# Activity Monitor Always Open Without Me Opening It

Tags: mojave, activity-monitor

Why is Activity Monitor randomly open all the time on my work laptop even though I never open it?? I'm using a Macbook Pro on Mojave.

Comment: Have you quit it properly? Not like cmd W but cmd Q?

Comment: Yes I have. That doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does Activity Monitor open up every time you restart your computer or every time you logout and login?

**If so**, check your `Login Items` under

```
System Preferences > Users & Groups > Your User > Login Items
```

Check if Activity Monitor is listed there. If so, remove it by selecting it and removing it using the minus sign.

**If not**, could you please clarify as to when it opens up and what action triggers it generally?

Comment: It seems to be doing it sometimes when I log back in. I don't usually shut down.

Comment: @TilmanNathaniel yes, this answer talks about login. Please check and remove it. If it solves, close the question:) !

Comment: It shows Login Options, I don't see Login Items. And I don't see anything about Activity Monitor.

Comment: So after you go to `Users & Groups` and click on your username in the left, see [here](https://i.imgur.com/1YwBJ84.png). Check if activity monitor shows up there in `Login Items`.

Comment: It's not listed under Login Items